# wordpress admin and wp-login not accessible

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

So I've got this friend  who asked me last year to convert her static dreamweaver website to wordpress. (the website is: http://marthart.be)

And so I did. And for a year, everything went okay. Today I got an email stating that she had login issues.

As it turns out I can't access http://marthart.be/wp-login.php or http://marthart.be/wp-admin . However, I duplicated wp-login.php to wp-login-oud.php (http://marthart.be/wp-login-oud.php) and that link actually DOES render the login page.

Both files have the same owner, same user rights, and same content. I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Another strange thing is that when I delete wp-login.php, the server doesn't give a 404 but it keeps trying to reach it, no matter what...

The Wordpress Version 3.5.1

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Check the `.htaccess` file. Some security plugins change the login path so that bots can't brute force

Comment: htaccess content:


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>